# android build Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION]

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I have got an apk and tried to install in my android device through the command prompt and finally ended up with this message. Don't know whats the problem. Any suggestions

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION]

Comment: But it has mentioned with EAS.    INSTALL_FAILED_EAS_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION

Answer (score 1):

Try going to device `Settings>Security` and check if `Unknown Sources` is checked, or try removing `Exchange Email`

Comment: Its checked only. I didn't check whether Exchange Email Account is there or not ? will check and try it. Thanks for your help